# How to properly do command substitution and concatenation in bash script and display output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to split the following command to use it in a script:

```
git diff HEAD --name-only && git submodule foreach git diff HEAD  --name-only | grep -v '^Entering')
```

So I've tried to do this:

```
GIT_CMD=$(git diff HEAD --name-only)
GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD=$(git submodule foreach git diff HEAD  --name-only)


CMD="$GIT_CMD && $GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD | grep -v '^Entering'"
echo $CMD
```

and the output I get is:

```
<file names> | grep -v '^Entering'
```

$GIT_CMD && $GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD are executed but I don't know what to do with the "| grep" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the command inside `$()` will execute the command and place the output in the variable.

Try:

```
GIT_CMD="git diff HEAD --name-only"
GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD="git submodule foreach git diff HEAD  --name-only"


CMD="$GIT_CMD && $GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD | grep -v '^Entering'"
echo $CMD
```

Now you are just assigning the command to the variable and not the output of the command.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So if I want to execute the command I have to do: CMD="$($GIT_CMD && $GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD | grep -v '^Entering')" right? Is it also possible to create a cmd for the "grep -v '^Entering"? I'm trying to but I can't get it to work. Something like: CMD="$(($GIT_CMD && $GIT_SUBMODULE_CMD)|$GREP_CMD)"

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried  `GREP_CMD="grep -v '^Entering'"` and it works in my machine.

Comment: On mine it doesn't. It prints: <filename> Entering moduleA <filename>